# Why is my method not returning an int?

Tags: java, methods, int, return

I've made a method that would take a string and an int and would return an int.
I want to know why it isn't working. (NumSLHorizontal cannot be resolved to a variable) Here's the relevant part of the code

```
for (int x = 1; x <= H; x++) {
        System.out.println("Introduza os " + V + " valores das rua " + x);
        String RuaTemp = input.next();
        Confirmador(RuaTemp, V);
        }
    System.out.println(NumSLHorizontal);



    input.close();
}
    public static int Confirmador (String RuaTemp, int V) {
        int NumSLHorizontal = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < V; z++) {
            char firstLetter = RuaTemp.charAt(z);
            if (firstLetter == '-') {
                NumSLHorizontal++;
            }

        }
        return NumSLHorizontal;
```

Comment: what is not working??, What is the actual behaviour??

Comment: Eclipse tells me that:
NumSLHorizontal cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Confirmador(RuaTemp, V);, here you should get the return value....

Comment: -1 for not identifying the line where the error was flagged.  Without that info it's far harder to see your bug.  When asking a question here, **always** include the entire error message and identify the line that was flagged.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result=0;
for (int x = 1; x <= H; x++) {
    System.out.println("Introduza os " + V + " valores das rua " + x);
    String RuaTemp = input.next();
     result = Confirmador(RuaTemp, V);
}
System.out.println(result);
input.close();
}
public static int Confirmador (String RuaTemp, int V) {
   int NumSLHorizontal = 0;
   for (int z = 0; z < V; z++) {
       char firstLetter = RuaTemp.charAt(z);
        if (firstLetter == '-') {
            NumSLHorizontal++;
        }
   }
   return NumSLHorizontal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return value to a variable:

```
int NumSLHorizontal = 0;
for (int x = 1; x <= H; x++) {
   ...
   NumSLHorizontal = Confirmador(RuaTemp, V);
}
System.out.println(NumSLHorizontal);
```

(Note that the way your code is structured it only keeps and prints out the value it got from the *last* call to `Confirmador()`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method that returns a value, you actually have to do something with the value.

Your method looks like:

```
public static int Confirmador (String RuaTemp, int V) {
    int NumSLHorizontal = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < V; z++) {
        char firstLetter = RuaTemp.charAt(z);
        if (firstLetter == '-') {
            NumSLHorizontal++;
        }

    }
    return NumSLHorizontal;
}
```

It appears that you thought that `return NumSLHorizontal` would put the result in `NumSLHorizontal` and that the rest of the program would then use that variable name to access the result.  That isn't what happens.  `NumSLHorizontal` is a **local variable** in the `Confirmador` method, and this variable can be accessed *only inside that method*.

As other answers have stated, in order to use the return value, you have to do something with the value when you call the method.  You can assign another variable to it:

```
result = Confirmador(RuaTemp, V);
```

or you could pass it along to another method:

```
System.out.println(Confirmador(RuaTemp, V));
```

or you could use it in an expression in any other way you could use an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

it might be better if you show all the code. from what i can understand from this code there is a scope problem.you are trying to output NumSLHorizontal that exist inside Confirmador from outside of this function.normally you shouldn't be able to compile this unless there is a global variable named NumSLHorizontal .if so ,it is overriden inside Confirmador.Correct me if am wrong.